# What do you call these symbols on either side of some text?

Tags: punctuation, symbols

Usually as part of a heading / sub-heading, you can often see symbols like in the image below on either side of the text:

[image: text "Short Phrase" between fleurons]

**I don't mean these symbols specifically**, just the general name for these symbols that illustrate that some text is *important* in a way. Another example is **tilde**s on either side of a phrase. It's been on my mind for embarrassingly long, and none of my web searches prove to be helpful.

The reason I ask: I'm trying to make a food menu that looks like those you see in a diner or the like. I'm pretty sure adding these types of symbols will make it look aesthetically pleasing, but I don't know how to search for this design inspiration without knowing what to call it.

Comment: It'll be a domain-specific (typesetting) term. Perhaps better asked on [Stack Exchange TEX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ...further to my comments under @psmears' answer, Maybe someone on Stack Exchange TEX could design you a pair of heterograms saying **Rob's** on one side and **Diner** on the other! I have no idea which letters can be successfully rotated / mirrored to give which *other* letters, but [**stay** + **here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ambigram_Stay_here_(animated).gif) looks neat, and *maybe* that could be tweaked to give **Eat Here.** (On a rotating sign outside your diner? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers tex.se is about one family of typesetting systems, not typesetting in general.  This would be off topic here as written, though a question about how to do it in (La)TeX etc. would be fine.  It seems more like a fit to [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

These look like [fleurons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleuron_(typography)):

> A fleuron, also known as printers' flower, is a typographic element, or glyph, used either as a punctuation mark or as an ornament for typographic compositions.

Comment: I suppose OP needs a matching pair of *mirror image* fleurons. I came across [***ambigram***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram) when I had a look myself, but Google doesn't offer much support for the collocation *"fleuron ambigram"* or *"ambigram fleuron"*. But now I've just found out about ***hetero-ambigram = heterogram*** ("special case ambigram that spells out *two different words* when rotated 180°) I gotta say that If ***I*** was gonna design that menu, I'd bust a gut to find a heterogram where the two different words were obviously food-related.

Comment: I remember being fascinated by Douglas Hofstadter's "Metamagical Themas" when I realised [the entire front cover of my copy](https://twitter.com/davidpapineau/status/1256119018857156615) was "palindromically" typeset. But how cool would it be to have a heterogram  saying, for example, ***Steak*** and ***Chips*** either side of your restaurant's name on the menu cards!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think "ambigram" is not what the OP wants. For one thing, an ambigram depicts *text* so that it can be read two ways. For another, an ambigram is *rotated*, not reflected.

Comment: @RosieF: Oh, come on! Hofstadter *invented* the word ambigram, and the link in my previous comment shows one of his very early ones! It's "mirror reflected", not "rotated".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I stand corrected. I'd never seen a reflecting one before.

Comment: @RosieF: It was 40 years ago when I read Hofstadter, so no surprise I didn't remember the word ***ambigram***. But the fact of the matter is I didn't even remember that fascinating book cover until I actually encountered an image of it online just now. I'm surprised to see they don't have that specific graphic on the front cover of current editions.

Comment: Thanks, all of you! And yeah I'd love to make an ambigram for a logo but man would that take a while haha. "Fleuron" is exactly what I wanted to incorporate into my site, so thanks @psmears

Comment: @FumbleFingers You probably already know this, but it is also an anagram of Martin Gardener's Mathematical Games.

Comment: Hello @FumbleFingers I have an offering for you, in return for the two fine image-linked comments that you provided for us earlier. Mine is evocative of your Stay+Here comment on the question: a [very special ambigram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ambigram_of_the_word_ambigram_-_rotation_animation.gif). I'm a hyper-active (though not at all hyperactive) user of Twitter, so I promptly viewed your link to that image of the front cover of the Metamagical Themas! I might respond to Papineau and link here, as his efforts are appreciated farther afield than he (perhaps) realizes.

Comment: @EllieKesselman: [Here's one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Featured_picture_candidates/Ambigram#/media/File:Tessellation_Fuck_90_degrees_rotational_symmetry_-_animation.gif) to really f**k with your head! :)

Comment: @PhilSweet: I probably ***used to*** know that 40 years ago when I was reading Hofstadter! I always looked at Gardner's column in New Scientist whenever my brother gave me his old copies, even though it often went over my head. I'm sure Hofstadter or one of the reviewers I read before buying his book would have pointed out the "inspiration" for the slightly peculiar title. I seriously doubt I'd have noticed it unaided though. (I do The Guardian cryptic crossword most days, but I often don't know there's a "theme" unless I end up going to fifteensquared.com for help with a troublesome clue! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was primed to be nonplussed as I read your comment, but immediately started laughing after I clicked the link!!! I still am lol'ing right now. Excellent find! (I hoped you were Papineau IRL but realized it was unlikely given his Twitter bio.)

Comment: @EllieKesselman (and PhilSweet): As either or both of you may know, [Roger Penrose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Penrose) (one of our leading mathematicians / physicists) is much preoccupied with tessellation lately (following in the footsteps of Escher). So it's not just "pretty pictures" - it's telling us something about how reality itself is "put together"!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have a cousin in Ayr that saves them for me and sends them at Christmas. I just finished a rather good NYT's Sunday puzzle ten minutes ago.

Answer (score 18):

In typography, these ornaments are called ❦ [dingbats](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/signs-and-symbols/dingbats) ❦

Here are some:

[image: dingbats]

<sub>Image source: [Beyond the Bullets: 6 Great Uses For Dingbat Fonts](https://community.articulate.com/articles/beyond-the-bullets-6-great-uses-for-dingbat-fonts)</sub>

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know this was a whole genre of font! I'll try to find one of these I love, thank you so much :)

Comment: https://www.fontspace.com/category/food,dingbats

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, the term [arabesque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabesque) is used for such decorative elements.